# Can I take profit in option trading if

Tags: investing, options, trading, call-options

If the current price of a stock is at 2000 and I take a call option buy at strike price 2100 weekly expiry with 80 ltp. Suppose now ltp increases by 5 points and yet the price does not go above 2100, will I make profit if the price is below while LTP is increased?

In my Portfolio it is showing profit, while the price does not go above. Please help me understand.

Comment: Does your broker allow you to sell the option again? Also, is the label actually "your profit", or maybe just "price change since you bought it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option basics: You paid 80 for the right to buy the stock at 2100. If you can sell the option for 85 (which means the *bid* is 85 - the last traded price is irrelevant), then yes, you could sell your option for 85 and make a profit regardless of whether the stock is above or below the strike. It just means someone *else* spent 85 for the right to buy stock at 2100.

You only get a payout at *expiry* if the stock goes above the strike , and profit if it is more than the premium you paid. *Before* expiry there are other factors that could cause a profit even if the stock price is below the strike. The expected volatility (uncertainty) of the stock could have gone up or the price could have gone up some but not enough to cross the strike.

But yes, you can sell options for a profit even if the stock does not cross the strike.

Comment: "You only profit at expiry if the stock goes above the strike."  For a long call at expiration, the profit is above the strike price plus the premium paid for the call.